# How to add the valus of duplicates same time matching with subject value

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet. like below,

```
ID#     AMT1     amt3
624982  402     402
625660  179     179
621506  274     274
621511  847     847
615950  2405    1285
615950  0       1121
122978  558     558
621517  1848    179
621517  0       1668
123016  3092    635
123016  0       2456
```

I need to add the values in (amt3) where duplicated ID# shown and which has total amount that is in (amt1). But still u can find that amounts in (amt3) are not equal. so I should be able to edit the number Eg(from-1121 to 1120) so the total will be equal to 2405. And still the amounts under (amt3) is linked with another sheet. so n when I edit manually the total changing. so please give me a good idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: PLease advise me how to show the details in spreadsheet

Comment: Have you tried using the "Consolidate" feature - found in the "Data" tab of the Ribbon in post-2007 versions.

Comment: No can u tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are seeking, but the *Consolidate* feature does much of what you are requesting (find "Consolidate" feature select the "Data" tab of the Ribbon in post-2007 versions).

My suggestion: 
1) Remove "Amt1"
2) Select *Consolidate*
3) Select:
 * Function = Sum
 * Reference = [yourTable]
 * Use Labels in: check both "Top row" and "Left column"

Your data will look like this:

```
        Amt3  
624982  402  
625660  179  
621506  274  
621511  847  
615950  2406  
122978  558  
621517  1847  
123016  3091
```

Any time you update your table, just re-run Consolidate.